# How to get data from attributes then disable buttons accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have run a bit of problem with our user interface, here's my code:

I have a button here inside a

```
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="btnSubmit" data-btn="{{ row[1] }}" data-id="{{ row[2] }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" contenteditable="false" disabled='disabled'> Pay</button>
```

I have been using `row[2]` from another function and it worked, so this time i used `row[1]` to evaluate data. The condition is that
when the `row[1]` of that row is empty the button would be disabled and would be colored to btn btn-danger and the text would be 
made to "Paid" however thorugh my attempts I only made everything disabled or perhaps the last entry only as disabled. Here's my latest attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

  var button = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
  var id = button.dataset.id;

  $('#btnSubmit').attr('data-btn').onkeyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() != '') {
       $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else{
      $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
    }

  });
});
</script>
```

And its disabling all buttons. I just want the bytton to be enabled when its empty and disabled if its empty, and again as Ive said  would be colored to btn btn-danger and the text would be  made to "Paid" how do I do this in this case?

I've read the documentations and everything but it didn't work for some reasons. I also tried having an invisible input and getting its id but no luck. Please help

Comment: You want to disable a button... Okay. Is that button appear on multiple rows? You want to disable it when WHAT is empty? An input maybe? If there is rows... Are they dynamically added/removed?

Comment: he meant 'data-btn' attr @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: Ha... okay, `data-btn` is the target to check for a value then?

Comment: i think so, reading his question, I have no idea how to solve it though currently trying on fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... Assuming that `data-bnt` is the target element to check on `keyup`.

*(I don't know what `data-id` is for...)*

And that the target must **not** be empty to enable the submit button.

Then try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      
      var button = $('#btnSubmit');
      var target = $('#'+button.data('btn'));
      
      target.on("keyup",function(){
        button.prop('disabled', ($(this).val() == '') ? true : false );
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="targetID">
<button
  class="btn btn-info"
  type="button"
  id="btnSubmit"
  data-btn="targetID"
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#myModal"
  contenteditable="false"
  disabled='disabled'> Pay</button>
```